# Java Stored Proc Not Executing

Tags: java, jdbc, sap-ase

I have a stored procedure call in my java code which uses sybase database as follows:

```
CallableStatement cstmt=sigmaConnection.prepareCall("{call dbo.sp_insRadEntry(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}");
cstmt.setString(1,"Nappa");
cstmt.setInt(2,40);
cstmt.setString(3,"Vegeta");
cstmt.setString(4,"Saiyan");
cstmt.setString(7,"Hello"); 

cstmt.execute();
```

As you can see i have deliberately not set the 5th and 6th parameter as my stored procedure has default values provided if any values are not passed and in this call call dbo.sp_insRadEntry(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) i have 7 parameteres as it was not allowing me to set the 7 th parameter without having 7 commas here.

But I'm getting the following exception even though I HAVE SET THE 4TH PARAMETER:

'java.sql.SQLException: JZ0SA: Prepared Statement: Input parameter not set, index: 4.'

Comment: Can you post the top portion of the create procedure statement (with the variables, default values, etc)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 'index 4' refers to the fifth parameter (index is zero-based) so I think the problem is that the default parameters are not being recognised by your code.

Comment: But I have to use only the defaults specified in the stored proc.So how do i modify my code so that only the values specified in the stored proc are used.

Answer (score 0):

You should try set the missing 5th and 6th parameter too, using setNull methods.

Comment: Tried that too but it gives another exception saying that "column does not allow nulls"

Comment: Yes tried that too.Retrns the exception that null values are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set value at Index  5 & 6 also

```
int type = TYPE
pst.setNull(index, type);
```

For TYPE refer here :  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-data-types.htm

**Edit:**  If you have Not Null constraints you have no way but set some dummy or blank values at those position which you will ignore while reading data(ehh..have to write some extra code for that check) and if you really don't want to do that then why have you set Not Null constraint in first place think of it. :-)

Comment: I tried the foll and it still return an exception as null values not allowed. `cstmt.setNull(5,java.sql.Types.CHAR); cstmt.setNull(6,java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);`

Comment: @gautamvegeta check your DB table does it have any `not null` constraints for column 5 & 6 .

Comment: Yes it does have those constraints.But that is why in my stored proc i have mentioned default parameteres.All i want to do is skip that paramter in the stored proc call in java.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will work in your DB, but what about omitting the question marks for the parameters you don't want to specify? That is:

```
CallableStatement cstmt=sigmaConnection.prepareCall(
        "{call dbo.sp_insRadEntry(?, ?, ?, ?, , , ?)}");
cstmt.setString(1,"Nappa");
cstmt.setInt(2,40);
cstmt.setString(3,"Vegeta");
cstmt.setString(4,"Saiyan");
cstmt.setString(5,"Hello"); 

cstmt.execute();
```